# glassfish hostname mapping

Tags: glassfish

with glassfish, i'd like to map say foo.domain.com to one context, and bar.domain.com to another context. is there a purely config way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure virtual servers as described [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19776-01/820-4507/abhfg/index.html) and assign your web-apps to them.

Example:

Add the following in the domain.xml inside the `<http-service>` element:

```
<virtual-server id="foo.domain.com" hosts="foo.domain.com" network-listeners="http-listener-1" />
```

Then edit the http-listener-1 setting in the `<network-config>` element. Change the port number, if the listener should listen to a different port:

```
<protocol name="http-listener-1">
   <http default-virtual-server="foo.domain.com" max-connections="250" server-name="foo.domain.com:8080">
   ...
</protocol>
```

Finally set the virtual server as default for your web application (in the `<server>` element. Replace app-name with the name of your webapp:

```
<application-ref ref="app-name" virtual-servers="foo.domain.com" />
```