# How to change host name Glassfish

Tags: java, web-services, soap, glassfish, server

I have troubles with glassfish server. I have created application in eclipse and war application, copied it to the remote server and delpoyed to glassfish. It recognized this web application and it works if specify url set it manually, by default it has following url

```
http://ubuntu:8080/TestService/TestServiceProvider?Tester
```

If set it to my server ip address manually it works great. How can I change ubuntu to my hostname.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should redirect your domain name to that ip address from your domain management site.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using HTTP service I'm also assuming you're using virtual servers.

According to [glassfish hostname mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5251122/glassfish-hostname-mapping)

setting "