# GlassFish hostname mapping on an AWS Ligthsail instance's public IP does not seem to work

Tags: apache, glassfish, windows-server-2016, amazon-lightsail

The instance is a Windows Server 2016. It runs an Apache server (for the ports 80 and 443), and a GlassFish server (on ports 8080 and 8181). On the machine itself, everything seems to work fine when I invoke localhost:.

I mapped the public IP of the instance to a DNS. When I invoke it with the Apache's ports it works fine, but not with the GlassFish ports. Same result when I use the public IP as well.

I tried to configure the Virtual host parameter directly from the GlassFish console (localhost:4848) and also the solution [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5251122/glassfish-hostname-mapping), without success. What am I missing here?

Comment: Does your firewall allow connections on ports 8080 and 8181 from outside of your server? It looks like it doesn't, if you're not able to connect even with the IP address. You don't need any special virtual host configuration in GlassFish if you only want to serve a single DNS domain.

Comment: I added a Firewall inbound rule exclusively for those 2 ports, but that did not help. But by reading you, I insisted a bit more on the firewall side of things. And I could finally make it work by disabling the Private Profile. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a firewall issue. Although I added inbound rules to allow for ports 8080 and 8181 explicitly, this wasn't enough.

I had to check a bit more (following the hint of @OndroMih in the comments of the post), and by disabling some sections of the firewall, it appeared that the Private Profile was the blocking one. Hence I disabled it.

Not sure what are the implications of that, but it solves my problem for now.